# I am trying to send email via Django but the request is not getting processed

Tags: django, email, django-views

The following is the view I wrote, no errors occur but no mail is getting sent to the receiver_email address.

```
def register_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    receiver_email = request.POST['email']
    passwd = generate_passwd()
    user  = User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=passwd,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
    res = send_mail("password",passwd,"theanirbanacharya@gmail.com",receiver_email)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:login',args=()))
```

What I am doing is generating a random password that I wish to mail to the user ( to the receiver_email ). But when I hit the "register" button nothing happens, the request is not getting processed. Not that anything is wrong with the template responsible for the registration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [SMTP Backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#smtp-backend) settings added your settings.py file? For example, gmail setting looks like:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = 1
```

Comment: may be check spam folder. and make sure that `receiver_email` has valid email address

Comment: No, the issue is that the mail is not getting sent at all. It would go into the spam folder if the mail was sent. But that is not happening at all. When I hit the register button, the browser seems to be waiting for the completion of the request and nothing happens thereafter.

Comment: In that case you are not connected to SMTP, or connection to SMTP is taking long time. Try using different SMTP

Comment: ok, I got the issue, Google is blocking the signing in attempt of my django app.

Comment: But after I changed the settings in google account, I was able to send mail from the shell, but when I run the server and try it, the issue remains the same.